# My java class can't load the interface

Tags: java, jframe

I have this java class ( it uses some external libraries ) , it should show me an interface but every time I run the app it shows nothing. Maybe I have some mistakes in the code?

```
public class FrameExample extends KaliActivity {
private static FrameExample example;
private Vector<JFrame> BCsFrames;

public FrameExample() {
    BCsFrames = new Vector<JFrame>();
}

// Main program for Kalimucho
public static void main(String[] args) {
    example = new FrameExample();
}
@Override
public void addPanel(BCModel cm, String panelName, JPanel panel,Object arg3) {
    System.out.println("ALOALALAOLAAOALAAOALOAALA");
    JFrame win = new JFrame(cm.getName() + ":" + panelName);
    win.setContentPane(panel);
    BCsFrames.addElement(win);
    win.pack();
    win.setVisible(true);


}

@Override
public void removePanel(JPanel panel) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while ((i < BCsFrames.size()) && (!found)) {
        if (BCsFrames.elementAt(i).getContentPane() == panel)
            found = true;
        else
            i++;
    }
    if (found) {
        BCsFrames.elementAt(i).dispose();
        BCsFrames.remove(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `addPanel` supposed to be called from?

Comment: Are you missing a call to super() in the constructor?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I didnt get it , what you mean ? the declaration ?

Comment: @SteveSmith I added super(); and still don t load any inetface

Comment: @MedAnis, no, the actual method. You instanciated the class and do nothing with it is what it looks like. Does it call methods on itself? What is `KaliActivity`?

Comment: addPanel is a method must be implemented by KaliActivity ( from an external library I added )

Comment: What is `KaliActivity`? Which "external library"? You might want to add that framework in the tags. Also, `BCsFrames` does not respect Java naming convention (i.e., it looks like a class name to me).

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you're just creating a `Vector<JFrame>`. Not *creating* any `JFrame` (or displaying them). Standard `JFrame` is displayed like:

```
JFrame win = new JFrame();
win.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("ALOALALAOLAAOALAAOALOAALA"));
win.pack();
win.setVisible(true);
```

I don't know what `KaliActivity` is, but you're probably missing a call to one of the `super()` constructor that instanciate a `JFrame` of some sort. It probably is doing some GUI object creation and display...